# JS regex replace not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a JS string

```
var str = '<at id="11:12345678">@robot</at> ping';
```

I need to remove this part of a string

```
<at id="11:12345678">@
```

So I am trying to use

```
var str = str.replace("<at.+@","");
```

But there is no change after excution. Moreover if I try to use **match** it gives me

```
str.match("<at.+@");
//Result from Chrome console Repl
["<at id="11:12345678">@", index: 0, input: "<at id="11:12345678">@robot</at> ping"]
```

So pattern actualy works but replace do nothing

Comment: Because you didn't pass in a regex! Try this: `var str = str.replace(/<at.+@/,"");`

Comment: Thanks! But why match works in that case?

Comment: Because [**`match`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is already expecting a regex so if you provide a string it will create a regex using `new RegExp`. But [**`replace`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) could take both a string litteral or a regex. If the parametter is a string then it will **not be transformed** into a regex it will just look for it as a string litteral and since there is no substring `"<at.+@"` it will replace nothing!

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `//` for `regex`. Replace `"<at.+@"` with `/<at.+@/`.

```js
var str = '<at id="11:12345678">@robot</at> ping'; 

str = str.replace(/<at.+@/,"");

console.log(str);
```

Documentation for [**replace**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)